# Why doesn't this loop work in paint() method?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, paint

**debugged and found the error...**

I tried doing this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mapWidth; i++) {
                g.drawRect (0 + i * (windowWidth/mapWidth), 0, windowWidth/mapWidth, windowHeight/mapHeight);
        }
}
```

and it paints nothing but when i do just this:

```
g.drawRect(0, 0, 64, 64);
```

it works perfectly?

Comment: Can you debug and see what the values are when you're trying to do the loop?

Comment: of course.. how i couldnt have thought of that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might seem easy but quite often, bugs tend to be trivial.

Have you checked if your variables do result in a value > 0, i.e.,

```
windowWidth/mapWidth   
//This would be 0 if mapWidth > windowWidth assuming both are ints.
```

Second, it seems to me that you have used two variables denoting the same thing:

```
getMapWidth  //Should this be a method?
mapWidth
```

Using two variables isn't a bug. However it may be possible that you have might have set an incorrect value in one of the two variables.

Comment: yeah that was a typo too when i tried to make a sscce.. -_- but yeah that was basically it

Answer (score 6):

Because you're putting zero in height in our first code, see the interface of [drawRect](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawRect%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29):

```
void    drawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Comment: @user2483938: oops, then you should probably figure the problem out by looking at the values stored in your variables ...

Comment: `that wasnt in my code` - well post your real code in the form of a `SSCCE` so we don't waste time guessing what your real code is.

Comment: No the constant zero I its origin y value